# How do I reattach a hunter douglas clutch cable?

Tags: blinds

My hunter douglas clutch cable, for their shades, has ripped open at what appears to be a glue line.

Is there a way to repair it without replacing it? (ie, some sort of glue or kit i can use)?

Comment: This [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/5ezYg_vd2P8) might be useful.

Comment: @Tester101 that video shows how to replace one, not fix/glue one that's ripped open

Comment: I know, just thought it might be useful, if you have to buy a new cord.